# Is Honda Accord gen 8 A/C Pressure Switch replacement DIY safe?

Tags: honda, accord, pressure, switches

I have a Honda Accord 2008.

I followed the Service Manual and identified that there is no continuity between the terminals of the A/C Pressure Switch. Since the refrigerant was only refilled last year, I plan to take a bet and order a new A/C Pressure Switch for replacement.

According to [this article](https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/how-to-replace-an-ac-pressure-switch-by-mia-bevacqua)  :

> Typically, the A/C system does not need to be evacuated prior to removing the A/C pressure switch. This is because there is a schrader valve built into the switch mount. If you have any doubt as to the design of your system, consult the factory repair information before switch removal.

But I couldn't find any information in the Honda Accord Service Manual whether there is a schrader valve built into the switch mount.

Does anyone know the answer or where I can find that out?

Comment: There has to be somewhere on there to check pressures as well as fill the system.

Comment: Ask a tech at Honda.

Comment: Or purge the system, change switch then refill, must be possible as you had it refilled last year.

Comment: I was hoping to do it at home and not go to the mechanics again @solar-mike

Comment: If you buy the switch or see photos with enough detail, you should be able to see if the threaded mount fits a schrader valve, and will press in on the center pin. (Looking briefly at rockauto, it doesn’t look like it fits a schrader valve. It threads into a female fitting.